# how to Build list view with a list to be rebuild as needed and constant part, to take advantage of the index in the list view

Tags: android, flutter, dart, listview, textfield

I'm working on comment page which I need to build the screen shown blow the first part is list veiw separated and second part is text field, but the problem is I can not use the **index** inside listview because the **textfiled** is outside the **listview.separated** tree.

So I figured if I was able to somehow get **textfiled** to be inside the **listview.separated**
I will be able to use the **index**, but the  **textfiled** keeps rebuilding and that's not what I want, is there anyway to stop it from rebuilding inside the **listview.separated** .

thanks
[image]

[image: postId indicates which post I will write the comment on]

**postId** indicates which post I will write the comment on

```
body: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.separated(
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                        buildCommentSection(context, index),
                    separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 10, bottom: 10, right: 20, left: 20),
                      child: Divider(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        thickness: 1,
                        height: 1,
                      ),
                    ),
                    itemCount: 1,
                  ),
                ),
                const Divider(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  thickness: 1,
                  height: 1,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    minLines: 1,
                    maxLines: 4,
                    controller: commentController,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Write a comment... ',
                      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 15.0, right: 15.0, top: 5, bottom: 5),
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[400]),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10, bottom: 10),
                  child: InkWell(
                    onTap: () {

//here to use the postComment function and I need the index here
                      SocialCubit.get(context).postComment(
                        SocialCubit.get(context).postsId[index],
                        comment: commentController.text,
                      );
                    },
                    child: const Icon(
                      Icons.send,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),


Container buildCommentSection(context, index) {
  return Container(
    // decoration: const BoxDecoration(
    //   image: DecorationImage(
    //     image: NetworkImage(
    //       'https://i.ibb.co/zGZyH0w/asd.jpg',
    //     ),
    //   ),
    // ),
    child: Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
              left: 65.0,
            ),
            child: Text(
              'Ahmad M. Hassanien',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1?.copyWith(
                  fontSize: 15, color: Colors.black, height: 1.3),
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              const Padding(
                  padding:
                      EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, top: 0, bottom: 10.0),
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 20,
                    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                        'https://scontent.fcai21-2.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.6435-9/36137473_1672721836179430_3456862169725927424_n.jpg?_nc_cat=104&ccb=1-5&_nc_sid=09cbfe&_nc_ohc=9tYeesdPuIQAX_nct-b&tn=vOLAikUZ_sGc5L8h&_nc_ht=scontent.fcai21-2.fna&oh=00_AT8Oo-xDechHRInJ_IBubDRLxcFftLHFysjrw5LF-iGpKg&oe=625A1564'),
                  )),
              Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 10, right: 15, top: 0, bottom: 10),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    readOnly: true,
                    minLines: 1,
                    maxLines: 50,
                    controller: commentController,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: commentController.text,
                      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 15.0, right: 15.0, top: 5, bottom: 5),
                      hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

---

```
   Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10, bottom: 10),
                  child: InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      //here to use the postComment function and I need the index here
                      SocialCubit.get(context).postComment(
                        SocialCubit.get(context).postsId[index],
                        comment: commentController.text,
                      );
                    },
                    child: const Icon(
                      Icons.send,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you need index of a list view? do you want to edit the preview comment?

Comment: I'm using firebase , and I need the index for the comment to indicate which post id I'm on

Comment: So you need the post id not comment? And try post your full code so that others can see and try to answer.

Comment: uploaded the code

Comment: Please post posts showing (widget) code, comment showing (widget), api calling codes so that we can understand the whole picture.

Comment: Please post posts showing (widget) code, comment showing (widget), api calling codes so that we can understand the whole picture